# Difference between rotational velocity and radial velocity?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, velocity

The Tully-Fischer Relation allows for the calculation of galactic mass using [the rotational velocity](https://dept.astro.lsa.umich.edu/ugactivities/Labs/tully_fisher/tf_intro.html). When looking at the NASA/IPAC Extragalactic Database, I find data for radial velocities from various reference frames:
[image: Basic Data for UGC 03475, with specific field selected][image: Calculated and corrected velocities for UGC 03475]

Is there any relation between these velocities? What exactly is the difference?

*(posted in the Physics SE for potential relevance that a distinction between types of velocities has to other topics in physics)*

Comment: well there is a glossary on the site, why not use it? For example I looked up LSR for you  ...

Comment: LSR 
(a) Local Standard of Rest -- An imaginary point, located at the Sun's distance from the Galactic center, that revolves clockwise around the Galaxy on a circular orbit. Astronomers measure a star's U, V, and W velocities with respect to the Local Standard of Rest rather than with respect to the Sun, because the Sun has a slightly noncircular orbit. The orbital velocity of the Local Standard of Rest around the Galaxy is about 220 kilometers per second. [C95]

Comment: (b) A frame of reference in which the mean motion of stars in the immediate neighborhood is zero. In such a reference system, the motions of stars in the Solar neighborhood (a volume of space about 100 pc in diameter) average out to zero (see Solar Motion). It is a coordinate system in which the origin is a point in the Galactic plane moving in a circular orbit around the Galactic center with a period equal to that of the Sun, and in which the three velocity components are Pi, in the direction from the galactic center to the origin; theta, in the

Comment: direction of Galactic rotation; and Z, perpendicular to the galactic plane. [H76]